# How can I add a "Add new" in a choices list in Symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony

I have two entities: `Song` and `Author`.The `Song` knows the `Author` with a `ManyToOne` relationship.

I generated the form for `Song` that I use in the new and edit pages. Here is what it looks like:

```
// ...
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
  $builder
    ->add('name')
    ->add('content')
    ->add('author') // That creates a "choices" list, exactly what I want.
  ;
}
// ...
```

I would like this `choices` list to have an "add new Author" entry that will display the `AuthorType` form, allowing me to add a new `Author`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like `SonataAdminBundle` does [demo admin page](http://demo.sonata-project.org/admin/app/post/create) (Login/pass: admin/admin). Add link to author popup form and after form submitting just update your author choice field via ajax.

The other way is to create `AuthorPickerType` custom form type where you will check if new author name is provided and not selected from the list of existing authors then create and return new author entity.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow this procedure http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html.

It explains how to do what you want, adding related element.